# Javascript :: New lines in textarea

Tags: javascript

In my HTML file I have this snippet of code:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="textfield" rows="10"></textarea>
```

And in my Javascript file I have this:

```
    input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    textfield = document.getElementById('textfield');

    if(document.getElementById('tmkbSelect').value == "option1") {
        document.getElementById('tmkb').innerHTML = "Tafel";
        for(input2i=0;input2i<20;input2i++){
            document.getElementById('textfield').value = input1+" "+"*"+" "+input2i+" "+"="+" "+input1*input2i;
        }
    }
```

I'm basically trying to create a multiplication table. It works, but not quite.

The javascript code is in a function and I call that function using a button, but the problem is that the output is this:

```
3 * 19 = 57
```

I want it to be:

```
3 * 1 = 3
3 * 2 = 6
3 * 3 = 9
```

And so on, how do I do this?
I need to do this using only Javascript.

Comment: `document.getElementById('textfield').value += `

Comment: Along with @putvande comment , you will want to add a "\n" to the end for the line break.

Comment: and you can collect a string with all text and set the value of your input just once, after the for loop.

Comment: Thanks everybody. It works, but still not quite. When I press the button once it shows up just fine, but when I press it again, the same table of multiplication is put right underneath the first. How do I "remove" the first so there's only one?

Comment: @user3611244: You only have that problem if you use the textarea value as temporary storage for the string as you build it. If you use an array or a string variable to build the string, it will replace the previous value when you finally put it in the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings and then put them in the textarea.

You can add the strings to an array, and then concatenate them after the loop and put them in the textarea:

```
var lines = [];
for(input2i=0;input2i<20;input2i++){
  lines.push(input1+" "+"*"+" "+input2i+" "+"="+" "+input1*input2i);
}
document.getElementById('textfield').value = lines.join('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **ShortHand** operator for adding content to textarea.

```
document.getElementById("test").value += "\n 1";
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/x3B3u/)

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, you assign the value:

```
... .value = input1+...
```

That means you overwrite the content every time. You need to append instead:

```
var content = '';
...
content += input1+...
...
document.getElementById('textfield').value = content;
```

Note the `+=`.

Don't forget to add `'\n'` after each line or everything will be in one line.